# Flex Access SwatchPanel from ColorPicker

Tags: apache-flex, events

I would like to access the SwatchPanel that is spawned on a ColorPicker open event. I need to move and resize the SwatchPanel in certain situations.

It appears that the dropdown variable which contains a reference to the SwatchPanel from the Color Picker is private.

I am at a little loss as to how I would now find a reference that I can access through the open event.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Yeah, damn those private variables! :)  I hate to have to C&P a whole class just to change a freaking var from private to protected.